# Unable to get results from database on successful ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

> I am a beginner, I unable to get the result from the database through ajax call in my PHP code.

Here is the sample php code with an ajax call.

```
  <script>
           $('.input').on('click',function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    method:'POST',
                    url:'',
                    data:{data_username:$('#username').val(),
                    data_lastname:$('#lastname').val()},
                    success:function(data){
                        var x =JSON.parse(data);
                        for(var index in x){         //here my error
                            console.log(x[index].username);
                        }
                        }

                    ,error:function(){
                        alert("failed!!!!!");
                    }

                });
            });
</script>
```

Comment: what error do you get?. Right after `var x =JSON.parse(data);` this line can you `console.log(x)` and look for the error message you get.

Comment: Are you sending ajax request to the same page and getting an error in the response?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code you posted suggests that you are sending the ajax request to the same page which leads me to think that the error you are receiving is because there is other HTML content all mashed up with the JSON content that you want. To prevent this from happening eithe rsend the request to a different page or use `ob_clean` before you begin sending the ajax query response and ensuring that the script finishes at the point of sending the data. Perhaps the following might help.

There is also a spelling mistake `$usernmae` should be `$username`!

```
<?php
    $use_live_db=false; # set to true to try running sql queries against db

    if( isset( $_POST['data_username'], $_POST['data_lastname'] ) ){
        /*
            when sending ajax to the same page you must ensure that ONLY the
            data you want is allowd to be sent - so using `ob_clean()` will
            discard any previously generated content from appearing in the
            output
        */
        ob_clean(); 

        /*
            I appreciate this is probably for testing but this is 
            simply yielding data you already know...
        */
        $username=$_POST['data_username'];
        $lastname=$_POST['data_lastname'];
        $sql='SELECT username, lastname FROM login where username=:one AND lastname=:two';

        $results=array(
            'username'  =>  $username,
            'lastname'  =>  $lastname,
            'sql'       =>  $sql
        );

        if( $use_live_db ){

            /* !!! CHANGE THIS TO THE APPROPRIATE FILE FOR YOUR SYSTEM !!! */
            require '/path/to/db-pdo.php';
            $results=array();

            $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );
            if( $stmt ){
                # think it should be bindParam rather than bindparam!
                $stmt->bindParam(':one',$username,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(':two',$lastname,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->execute();

                while( $row=$stmt->fetch() ){
                    $results[]=$row;
                }
            }else{
                exit('error: failed to prepare sql query');
            }
        }

        /*
            Similarly to using `ob_clean()` you must prevent the remainder of
            the current page appearing as part of the ajax response - 
            so use `exit` or `die`
        */
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        exit( json_encode( $results ) );
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>jQuery & AJAX - POST request to PHP script to interrogate db</title>
        <script src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type='text' id='username' name='username' value='mike' />
            <input type='text' id='lastname' name='lastname' value='hunt' />
            <input type='button' class='input' value='OK' />
        </form>
        <script>
            $('.input').on('click',function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    method:'POST',
                    url:location.href,
                    /*
                        If you set the dataType
                        properties jQuery automagically ensures
                        the response is in the correct format- JSON
                    */
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data:{
                        data_username:$('#username').val(),
                        data_lastname:$('#lastname').val()
                    },
                    success:function( json ){
                        console.info('username: %s\nlastname: %s\nSQL: %s', json.username, json.lastname, json.sql )
                        alert('ok')
                    },
                    error:function(){
                        alert('failed!!!!!');
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i append your code instead of my code and not print anything in console but implement   error:function(){alert(("failed !!!!");}

Comment: OK - I don't use jQuery so I apologise for the error- remove `contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',` and try

Comment: i'am so sorry  code is not run with me please help me